# I can't login with a user I created in sql azure

Tags: sql, authentication, azure

I created a login and a user in sql azure but i'm not able to login...
I can connect only with the administrator account...

How do I login with the user I created?

Comment: You are going to need to provide a lot more info - at least what you mean by 'not able to login'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been struggling with this too, and after some research it appears that only LOGINS can login. A User (created in a specific database, from a login) is only a "persona" that a login assumes when accessing that particular database.

So, again, you can't login as a User, only with a Login. If your intention is to somehow create restricted access to a specific database then you need to do some work: I'm currently looking at the following article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/2012/01/21/sql-azure-create-a-login-that-has-only-access-to-one-database-sql-azure-cr-233-er-un-login-qui-n-a-acc-232-s-qu-224-une-base-de-donn-233-es.aspx

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to use SQL Server Management Studio you need to specify the database that you want to connect to (Login screen -> Options -> Connection Properties) as by default new logins do not have access to the master database which SSMS will try to open if a database is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure SQL Database security works mostly like standard SQL Server, in that you have to ensure that you have a server login created for that user, as well as a user created in the database linked to the login. Look at the Docs for more information to make sure you aren't missing a step: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336235.aspx